# Multiple Subdomains pointing to one website in IIS

Tags: iis-7, subdomain, bindings

My website is running on a domain (for example) `www.mydomain.com`. Now the problem is that `abc.mydomain.com`, `xyz.mydomain.com` etc. (`*.mydomain.com`) are pointing to the same website. We have a binding in IIS on port 80 for "All Unassigned". Is that binding causing the problem, or does this have something to do with DNS configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a CNAME record for *.mydomain.com which point to IP Address of your website. Then all request will be forwarded to your application IP Address. This is issue of your DNS provider.